# What is the distance travelled by an object moving in a circular motion, the origin of which, is also moving in a circular motion?

Tags: circular-motion

I'm trying to calculate the distance moved by an object rotating on a spindle, if that spindle is also rotating around a larger spindle (similar to earth moving around the sun). Hopefully you can see the image attached (but info summarized below anyway) It's related to motion of a polishing machine - see youtube link below at time 1:20 so you get the idea. i.e. what is the total distance a part would move given the following info. Also would like to calculate the angular and linear velocity

- time = 10 minutes
- larger circle radius = 50 mm
- larger circle RPM = 40 RPM
- smaller circle radius = 20 mm
- smaller circle RPM = 30 RPM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU7CqFej17I&t=1m24s  (see 1:24)

[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdN6M.png)

Comment: Have you tried the [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can describe the position of the particle as follows:

point on big circle:

$p_b = \Big(50\sin(2\pi\cdot40t),\ 50\cos(2\pi\cdot40t)\Big)$

point on small circle if it were centered on the origin:

$p_s = \Big(20\sin(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0)),\ 20\cos(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0))\Big)$

point on small circle with center on big circle:

$p_p = p_b+p_s = \Big(50\sin(2\pi\cdot40t)+20\sin(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0)),\ 50\cos(2\pi\cdot40t)+20\cos(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0))\Big)$

We can write this as

$$p_x = 50\sin(2\pi\cdot40t)+20\sin(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0))$$
$$p_y = 50\cos(2\pi\cdot40t)+20\cos(2\pi\cdot20(t+t_0))$$

(You can use your favorite plotting software to look at this path if you want)

Here:

- $t$ is in minutes
- $t_0$ is an offset from where you start on small circle ($t_0=0$ means starting all the way out)
- The position of the point is described in mm.

You should then do this numerically.

Here's what [WolframAlpha came up with](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arc+length+50sin%2880+pi+t%29%2B20%5Csin%2840+pi%28t%2B0%29%29+and+50%5Ccos%2880+pi+t%29%2B20%5Ccos%2840+pi%28t%2B0%29%29+from+t%3D0+to+t%3D10): It gives an exact answer with value $96000 E(5/9)\approx126923.5167$ where $E$ is [this funny function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Trying different values for $t_0$ doesn't make a difference, the total distance is always 126923.5 mm.

Comment: Note that a closed form formula is possible, involving an elliptic integral of the second kind as [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28A+%2B+B+cos%28C+x%29%29) shows. Try to redo it with symbols such as $R, r, \theta, \omega$ instead of numbers.

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you, I edited the exact answer given by WolframAlpha into my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help folks, just trying to digest the solution now!